# Redisson Blocking Queue Element Subscribe Failing

Tags: redis, redisson, keydb

I am attempting to create Job Queues using Redisson's `RBlockingQueue`. Using their `subscribeOnElements` method successfully delivers new Elements until that worker has to sent elements back, then no more elements end up being delivered. Using KeyDB CLI to debug, I am able to confirm that the sent elements definitely do end up being in the queue, the method just isn't picking up on them. Any ideas?

```
@Getter
public abstract class QueueConsumer<T> extends Queue<T> {
    private int listenerId;

    protected QueueConsumer(String queueName) {
        super(queueName);
    }

    public abstract void receive(QueueMessage<T> message);

    @Override
    void initialize() {
        listenerId = getQueueManager().getBlockingQueue(this).subscribeOnElements(this::receive);
    }
}
```